Why Wegene and Gedmatch (raw data uploaded from wegene) gives me similar results in everything except on the European part?


The first is wegene， the second is Gedmatch with raw data uploaded from wegene and the EUtest V2 K15.
In everything both websites seems to coincide.
However, what I cannot understand is how could wegene confuse my European ancestors with 'Balkans' in such of high numbers, but give me such low scores on Spanish which is, in theory, where my European ancestries should come from.
If the family tradition is true (I'm from southamerica）, I am totally sure that if they compare my DNA with a Balkanic and with a Spaniard, it will show more connection to the Spaniard, as simple as that.
K15 does not seems to have a 'Spanish' category, but it has North Atlantic and North Sea, as the highest European rate, while Eastern Euro is veeery low which should coincide with Balkanic.
Other admixtures in Gedmatch (which I don't remember the name) has more cateogories including: Iberian, French, Baque, and it shows a high percentage on 'Iberian', it did not show anything particular on that other side of Europe.
To add to the mistery, K15 shows more 'North Sea' than West Med, if my ancestors are spanish should not be stronger on the west Med?
